# Issue with ban command discord.py (rewrite branch)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've been programming a bot with discord.py (the rewrite branch) and I want to add a ban command. The bot still doesn't ban the member, it just shows an error:

```
@client.command(aliases=['Ban'])
async def ban(ctx,member: discord.Member, days: int = 1):
    if "548841535223889923" in (ctx.author.roles):
        await client.ban(member, days)
        await ctx.send("Banned".format(ctx.author))
    else:
        await ctx.send("You don't have permission to use this command.".format(ctx.author))
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.roles)
```

It'll ban the pinged user and confirm that it did ban

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Member.roles` is a list of `Role` objects, not strings.  You can use `discord.utils.get` to search through that list using the id (as an int).

```
from discord.utils import get

@client.command(aliases=['Ban'])
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, days: int = 1):
    if get(ctx.author.roles, id=548841535223889923):
        await member.ban(delete_message_days=days)
        await ctx.send("Banned {}".format(ctx.author))
    else:
        await ctx.send("{}, you don't have permission to use this command.".format(ctx.author))
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.roles)
```

There also is no longer a `Client.ban` coroutine, and the additional arguments to `Member.ban` must be passed as keyword arguments.

Comment: Thanks! So, what if my bot joins another server..? What do I replace the Role ID with so this works universally?

Comment: That depends what you're looking for.  A role with a certain name, permission to ban members through discord itself, etc.

Comment: K, I've got the command, it's `commands.has
_permission(ban_members = True)`, thank for the help!

Answer (score 0):

````
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, *, reason=None):
  if reason:
    await member.send(f'You got banned from {ctx.guild.name} by {ctx.author}, reason: ```{reason}```')
    
    await member.ban()
    
    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} got banned by {ctx.author.mention} with reason: ```{reason}```')
  if reason is None: 
    await ctx.send("please specify a reason")
````

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes